# Incomplete key signature - reason and name

Tags: notation, key-signatures, accidentals

I just now encountered the 2nd example of the following:

- established publisher
- baroque period
- the piece is clearly in e.g. c minor (related to e flat major, 3 bs)
- the printed key signature shows less bs (here: 2 instead of 3), adding accidentals, where necessary

Some research in the internet gave these reasons:

- key signatures were not [up to and including Haydn] standardized for minor (due to melodic vs. harmonic variants, or possible blurring between Dorian mode and minor key)
- avoid intimidation of potential buyers/players
- tuning more problematic with increasing number of signature symbols

While I understand at least the first reason, I'm unsure, why a new edition would keep the old tradition.

Is there any further reason for the approach?

Does this practice have a name?

Comment: This was already answered here: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50938

Comment: " I'm unsure, why a new edition would keep the old tradition." On the contrary, why should a new edition change what the composer wrote, just to satisfy the whims and fancies of the today's "musical notation style police"?

Comment: @alephzero: Do you question the right to exist for any edition  not urtext? In my opinion any non-professional player is thankful for any non-intrusive help she can get from the editor. And if, as in the case of Haydn, the incomplete signatures were only kept for historical/habituation reasons, I question them seriously today.